# Where should a daemon started by launchd store its data?

Tags: launchd, defaults, daemons

When I develop UI application for OSX I store user's preferences and application config to `~/Library/Preferences/AppName.plist` (using NSUserDefaults).

But when I create global background daemon that will be running using `launchd` on behalf of `root` - what is the better place to store daemon's config?

On Linux I would put it to the `/etc/` directory, but I'm not sure I can do the same on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

## Dynamic Paths

On macOS, a process asks the operating system where to save specific types of files using the `NSWorkspace` method [URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory). There is a CoreFoundation C equivalent function for this method.

This approach mimics the goals of the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) on other platforms.

### Typically `/Library`, however…

Before macOS 10.15, computer wide processes, such as daemons, used the `/Library` folder structure:

- For preferences: `/Library/Preferences/`
- For cached files: `/Library/Cache/`
- For general support and runtime files: `/Library/Application Support/`

See [What is the purpose of each folder under /Library and /System in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/104547/what-is-the-purpose-of-each-folder-under-library-and-system-in-mac-os-x)
 for a good overview of the various folders and their intended purpose.

However, macOS 10.15 changes the file structure and limits large parts of the core system read-only. Shipping with fixed file paths and assuming those paths to have read-write access is risky.

Comment: Great answer, but since I’m not sure how Catalina is going to set up the firm links - I’m going to suggest they use `/usr/local/etc` which is called out as explicitly going to be in the read/write portion of the read only file system that is coming soon to planet macOS.

Comment: That is a good point. A good process asks macOS for the appropriate folder and uses the supplied URL. I will extend my answer.

Comment: This is even better with the API calls - super useful.

Answer (score 0):

For a very safe option, I would write into `/usr/local/etc` if you wanted to sandbox / persist a configuration file for your daemon.

Also, it’s totally expected that the daemon would simply have the ability to accept command line arguments when launched and you would then store all of these in the preference list that invokes the system. Then relaunch the daemon when the `launchd` task gets reloaded allows you to change things up on the system as it’s running.